# Apache Flink Job submission through REST API failed

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-batch

I have a local Apache Flink Cluster version 1.16.3 installation as specified [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/deployment/resource-providers/standalone/overview/). I have uploaded the jar file through the Flink UI and I am trying to start the job using the Flink REST API.The job submission reaches the Flink job Manager and the job submission immediately gets failed with the following exception,

```
InvalidProgramException: Job was submitted in detached mode. Results of job execution, such as accumulators, runtime, etc. are not available.
JarRunHander- Exception occured in REST handler:could not execute application
```

Do the job submission through the REST api requires any additional configuration apart from Main class and command line arguments?

Answer (score 0):

The submission is made using the detached mode in the REST API. Some functions (such as accumulators, runtime, etc.) are not available in detached mode. You can either use the attached mode for submission via the command line or remove the relevant operators.

You can provide more detailed descriptions or code in order for me to help you more.